# Regular Expression to remove html tags from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am fetching my resut from a RSS feed using following code:

```
try:
    desc = item.xpath('description')[0].text
    if date is not None:
        desc =date +"\n"+"\n"+desc
except:
    desc = None
```

But sometimes the description contains html tags inside RSS feed as below:

> This is samle text
>
> < img  src="http://imageURL" alt="" />

While displaying the content I do not want any HTML tags to be displayed on page. Is there any regular expression to remove the HTML tags.

Comment: i think this will be appropriate! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags.

Comment: @Jeroen: No, it isn’t appropriate.  It’s stupid. Didn’t you read the question at all?  **HE’s ALREADY USING xpath!!!** Will you people just lay off and use your brain for a change?

Comment: @tchrist: I may misunderstood something, but currently it seems to me like you didn't really read his question. He is using a xpath, right, but what he gets after evaluating it, is HTML. And beside that fact: no need to be unfriendly, bro.

Comment: @naeg: I very strongly feel that that 1732348 answer is simply a joke that gets repeated incredibly too often. It does not help people. I find it very unfriendly, so I downvote it every chance I get.

Comment: @tchrist: it imo helps, because it explains that using regex to parse html/xml is just wrong and you should be using some parser. I read that answer for the first time and found it funny and right (not only the accepted answer to the question, also others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pattern = re.compile(u'<\/?\w+\s*[^>]*?\/?>', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
text = pattern.sub(u" ", text)
```

Comment: @naeg: Regular expressions works fine for this case. A better solution could be `text = lxml.html.fromstring(text).text_content()` but requires extra packages.

Comment: did you read the link? Just don't use regex to parse html in general, there can always be cases where your regex will fail hard and mess up everything.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way:

```
def remove_html_tags(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return pattern.sub('', text)
```

But for a more robust solution, I'd recommend looking into [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to this without using regex. It's a robust solution:

```
def remove_html_markup(s):
    tag = False
    quote = False
    out = ""

    for c in s:
            if c == '<' and not quote:
                tag = True
            elif c == '>' and not quote:
                tag = False
            elif (c == '"' or c == "'") and tag:
                quote = not quote
            elif not tag:
                out = out + c

    return out
```

The idea is explained here: http://youtu.be/2tu9LTDujbw

You can see it working here: http://youtu.be/HPkNPcYed9M?t=35s

PS - If you're interested in the class(about smart debugging with python) I give you a link: http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs259/CourseRev/1. It's free!

You're welcome! :)